# change tvOS tab bar focus color

Tags: uitabbar, appearance, tvos13

I created an appleTV app on tvOS 13! and I'm faced with some tabbar customization problems.
I want to change the focused item color, I can change the text color, but I can't change the white focus background!

[image]

And also the tabBar add an alpha to 0.5 on not selected image how to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On tvOS 13 you need to access the standardAppearance to change it:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.standardAppearance.selectionIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Yep I can change the selectionIndicatorTintColor to red or else but I won't it to be clear and when I set it to clear there still a background to white -_-